# Insert bulk data in ContentVersion with Bulk API

Tags: bulk-api, contentversion, enterprise-wsdl

We are working on a migration application in C# to migrate data from SQL Server to Salesforce and we are using Bulk API and sforceService (Salesforce Enterprise WSDL) for this. We are migrating data with batches and jobs.

My question is that can we programatically upload/insert data in ContentVersion in a batch as well with Bulk API? If so, how please provide some sample code/reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to upload Content by using Salesforce Dataloader.
Please refer below link for more detail :

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_content.htm

While uploading "Content" through SF Dataloader, you can provide a attribute "PathOnClient", which is the local path of your machine from where you are uploading files to SF.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I saw that documentation that you suggested; it suggests a way on how to do from the UI from Data Loader. But my requirement is to do that programatically. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: ^ use a bean! That's just fun to say https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line

Comment: thanks @cricketlang for the input. Lemme have a look at it.